# How to make selected-folder text more legible in Marlin File Manager?

Tags: themes, marlin

In my Ubuntu 12.04 I installed Marlin File Manager.

It's difficult for me to read the text of a selected file/folder. It surrounded by red line and background is white and text is grey. Hard to read.

In my screenshot, it faded to white. But I want to know how I can change its text and highlight color properties.

[image: Screenshot of issue]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem fully, but have you tried to adjust the Universal Access options from System Settings??

Comment: I clicked on Display folder. And you can see I cant read Display text. Because it's font and background color both became white. In my default file manager, there is no such issue. Only happening in Merlin. Let me fine Universal Access options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been reported as a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/marlin/+bug/993603). The problem seems to be present only when default Ubuntu theme (Ambiance) is in use. The best workaround is to change the theme.

There are numerous [themes](http://gnome-look.org/) available online for Ubuntu, Just Google it. Hare's the [theme](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php?content=148398) I'm currently using and Marlin is working perfectly with it.

[image]

**How to install the theme:**

1. Unpack the downloaded \'tar.gz\' archive to your home .themes folder, if there isn't any just create one.
2. Use Myunity, Gnome Tweak Tool or Ubuntu Tweak to use the theme.

Comment: This trick works. I changed the theme.